# how to enable muc room core-data storage use it for offline accessing

Tags: ios, chat, xmppframework, muc

I am working on group chat. I have successfully created group but could not storing group in core-data and not able to join that group also(Which is created already).
how to parse fetched  group list  and parse on fetch from core-data classes....

Comment: Hi BalKrishan, I on same stage you were can you share any solution for this.

Comment: check if it helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038176/how-to-save-and-fetch-in-xmppgroupcoredatastorageobject