# How to save and fetch in xmppGroupCoreDataStorageObject?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xmppframework

Using `xmpp-messenger-ios`, I have created the group and set its configuration and adds the users into it, then I wants to add the group into the `xmppGroupCoreDataStorageObject` storage to list it into the OpenChatViewController table view.

**How I am saving the Group Data into xmppGroupCoreDataStorageObject:**

```
public class func addUserInCoreData(jid:String, users: Set<NSObject>) {

        let moc = OneRoster.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext_roster() as NSManagedObjectContext?
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        person.setValue(jid, forKey: "name")
        person.setValue(users, forKey: "users") // Code breaks here.
        print(moc.debugDescription)

        do{
            try moc?.save()
            let sucess = XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject.insertGroupName(jid, inManagedObjectContext: moc)
            print(sucess)
        }
        catch let error{
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

**Encountering the Exception:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf8c545e50'***
```

**Here is the Framework Implementation:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet* users;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you are saying that it crashes on the setValue for `users` line, one guess would be that your `users` set doesn't really contain objects of type `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject` (but it's supposed to). I think your method signature should be:

```
public class func addUserInCoreData(jid: String, users: Set<XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject>)
```

Check the place where you call this function, it might be the case that you are passing a set of not `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject` objects, but some different type, which is wrong.

**But probably even more importantly:**

```
let entity = XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject.insertGroupName(jid, inManagedObjectContext: moc)
```

should be called **instead** of

> let entity =
>   NSEntityDescription.entityForName("XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject",
>   inManagedObjectContext: moc!)

and **not** after `try moc?.save()`. This method returns a `XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject` object that should be configured and then saved, not a bool indicating a successful save.

Check out, for example, this tutorial (note the `saveName` method in the Saving to Core Data part):
https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Good luck!

Comment: bro can you help me to solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172852/how-to-parse-xmppmessage-element-attribute-and-node-in-xmppframework-with-swif ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are trying to send the message to an object that cannot respond to it.
Look at your exception log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf8c545e50'***
```

`managedObjectContext` message has been sent to an instance of `NSString` class.
Of course, it cannot respond to it and you are getting the crash.