# How to parse xmppMessage element , attribute and node in XMPPFramework with Swift3?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, xmppframework

```
 func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didReceive message: XMPPMessage!){
print(message)
}
```

The result is like the following format,

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="pubsub.mynet.com" to="002225743@mynet.com" type="headline">
    <event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event">
        <items type="headline" node="mynet.global">
            <item id="1495526003">
                <xml>
                    <title>My Net</title>
                    <about>Good for you!</about>
                    <published>2017-05-23 14:23:23</published>
                </xml>
            </item>
        </items>
    </event>
    <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="admin@mynet.com/jaxl#5022c770097cfbce285d9564a960f9c7" stamp="2017-05-23T07:53:23Z"/>
</message>
```

How to get `<about>`  in `<xml>`.If anyone had answer and ideas , please help me my problem.

Comment: So an XmppMessage is an DDXmlElement, use msg.forName('event') to get the 'event', and so on.